# Syntax for handling null values nicely

Tags: c#

When returning an object that may be *null* but mustn't I usually go with the (what its proper name?!) very-surprised operator: *??* like so.

```
return hazaa ?? new Hazaa();
```

The problem arises when I return a property of the object (in case it exists) and some default value otherwise. Not that the check of nullness is to be done on the parent object. Today I do like so.

```
return hazaa != null
  ? hazaa.Property
  : String.Empty;
```

I think it's a less than optimal syntax and I'd like it more compact (but still easily understandable, given that the property is implemented appropriately) like so.

```
return (hazaa ?? new Hazaa()).Property;
```

However, I dislike the parentheses and I'm looking for a syntax that omits them, still being compact. Is there such a thing in C#? I'm looking for something like this.

```
return hazaa ?.Property :String.Empty;
```

And, spinning on the thought, something like this.

```
return hazaa ?.Property :.BackUpProperty;
```

I could create my own property layer that gives me such behavior but that's just hiding the issue.   :)

Comment: "null-coalescing operator", though I think I like the "very surprised operator" better.

Comment: No, basically there's nothing in C# like the null-safe dereferencing operator from Groovy.

Comment: Wait, this would actually work ? `(hazaa ?? new Hazaa()).Property;`

Comment: @Dimitar: Certainly. Why not?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth No I just thought that If it's null in this situation it would just throw an error. Not sure why I'm under that impression.

Comment: @Dimitar: `??` is the null-coalescing operator. It basically is short for `hazaa != null ? hazaa : new Hazaa()`. This should illustrate that there is no case where you actually would call `Property` on `null`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yeah, it's kinda obvious now. I feel like an idiot ...

Comment: @Dimitar: No need to. If you learned something new, everything is fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in this topic, you should do some reading on monads. On the `Maybe` monad in particular. This should get you started: http://devtalk.net/csharp/chained-null-checks-and-the-maybe-monad/

There is no inbuilt syntax to simplify null checks in C#, sadly.

Comment: There should be one. Maybe in C# 5.0.

Answer (score 3):

A Maybe monad might be a possible alternative.

Depending on the implementation it could look like this:

```
May.Be(hazaa, x => x.Property, string.Empty);
```

or

```
May.Be(hazaa).Select(x => x.Property, string.Empty);
```